# How to distribute an iOS app for a certain number of the devices?

Tags: ios, app-store, distribution

I work in a company, a client ordered an internal iOS app for his company.
What am I supposed to do to give him the application only for his devices without appstore? Do I need a special developer account? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To distribute iOS applications internally or to a limited number of clients, you will need to be member of the Apple iOS Developer Enterprise Program, currently the price is $299 / year. For more information, take a look at this [article at developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/).

Comment: -1 : The iOS Enterprise program is only for distribution to employees, not clients.  It also requires being a D&B rated corporation.

Comment: as hotpaws2 wrote: The client will need to do the paperwork and register for the Enterprise Program. The OP can then do the work and create and distribute the app in the name of the registered client.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of devices is less than 100 per year (including all replacement and upgrade devices), the client can get their own iOS Developer enrollment and use Ad Hoc deployment.

If you use your own developer account, you may run out of allowed devices, and end up out of business till next year.  So that's not recommended.  Have the client enroll, and then have them let you use their account for deploying apps for their devices.

Ad Hoc app deployment requires renewing certificates and provisions every year to keep the apps running.

If the number of the client's iOS devices is much greater than 100, then for deployment to stock OS iOS devices, you may have no choice but to submit the app to Apple's app store.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Apple Support regarding to this question, and got this answer:

Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Support regarding our programs.

Companies who wish to work with consultants or contractors should themselves enroll their company in the iOS Developer Program Standard or Enterprise program. The developer should keep in mind that the employee submitting the enrollment must have authority by their company to bind the company to legal agreements on behalf of the company. At this time, each client must have their own Apple Developer Account if located outside of the US.

Once accepted in to the program, the company may then add their consultant or contractor to their Team Member list as a user or admin. The company Team Agent would then later submit their application to the App Store under their own company account/name.